# Spring boot call to a Sql file

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a small query regarding the Spring boot logic of calling the sql files. I know that the schema sql files are called automatically if they are kept inside the resource directory of the spring boot app project. 
But i would like to call them from a different directory. I have written the below code to try and achieve that but fails with below error message.

**Code :**

```
public void executeSqlScript()throws SQLException{
  Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
  connection.setAutoCommit(false);
  ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(connection, new EncodedResource(new ClassPathResource("C:\\react-file-upload-master\\createConfigurationTableAndData.sql")));
  connection.commit();
}
```

**Error Message : java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [C:/react-file-upload-master/createConfigurationTableAndData.sql] cannot be opened because it does not exist.**

Its is not reading my directory. Would be greatfull if you could educate me on the same. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `FileSystemResource` instead of `ClassPathResource` and give absolute path.

```
public void executeSqlScript()throws SQLException{
  Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
  connection.setAutoCommit(false);
  ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(connection, new FileSystemResource("C:\\react-file-upload-master\\createConfigurationTableAndData.sql"));
  connection.commit();
}
```

because ClassPathResource will point to class path only. assuming your file is not in classpath.

Comment: Yea i got to know my mistake and trying to change the logic. I will update you once i try the same. Thank you!!